# C++ macros and errors encountered

Tags: c++, macros

I am using a program to verify certain results and I would like to replace my function calls with macros to speed up the verification process.

However, my initial attempts to replace simple functions with macros have always resulted in compiler errors.

The macro, mMul, in the attached code has to be designed to multiply two hexadecimal numbers. Since the code for multiplying has more procedures in it, I have shortened it to just XOR two hexadecimal numbers.

But compiling this code always gives the compiler error

```
In function 'int main()'::
expected primary-expression before '{' token
expected ';' before '{' token
```

at the line 'cout << mMul(a, b)'

I believe my code is syntactically correct. But I just do no understand what this error is telling me.

Any help/ advice with this code and on how to design a proper macro will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream> // for cin and cout
#include <stdint.h> // to define uint8_t

using namespace std;

#define mMul(a,b)   \
{                   \
uint8_t prod = 0x00;\
prod = a^b;         \
}

int main()
{
int a, b;

cin >> hex >> a;
cin >> hex >> b;

cout << mMul(a, b);

cin.get();
cin.get();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why use macros - they are bad news. C++ has `inline` - a lot better

Comment: What do you mean, "speed up the verification process"? No matter what you do, the majority of time spent in this program will be taken by the OS creating and destroying its process.

Answer (score 1):

After macro expansion (remembering that macros are just a text replacement that happens before compilation) your code is:

```
cout << { uint8_t prod = 0x00; prod = a^b; };
```

which is a syntax error.  To fix this, you could use the correct syntax for a lambda. However it seems better style to just use a function:

```
inline uint8_t mMul(int a, int b)
{
    return a ^ b;
}
```

Note that this will output the character value (not the integer value), since `uint8_t` is a typedef for `unsigned char`. To get the integer value you could have your function return `uint16_t`, or you could write `cout << static_cast<unsigned int>( mMul(a,b) );`. Also I would think more about about what types `a` and `b` should have.

Comment: May I know what you meant by "you could use the correct syntax for a lambda"? Never came across inline before, so thanks for introducing it to me

Comment: In this case the code would work just as well without `inline`, but if you move this function to a header file you'd have to make it inline.

Answer (score 0):

You canNOT simply replace function calls with macros, especially when return values are involved.

In your case, either you will have to replace functions with other (diagnostic) functions or do the following change to your macro and code.

```
#include <iostream> // for cin and cout
#include <stdint.h> // to define uint8_t

using namespace std;


#define mMul(a, b)\
uint8_t prod = 0x00;\
prod = a^b;\
cout << prod; // cout should be here.

int main()
{
int a, b;

cin >> hex >> a;
cin >> hex >> b;

mMul(a, b); // cout is removed from this line.

cin.get();
cin.get();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,

```
#include <iostream> // for cin and cout
#include <stdint.h> // to define uint8_t

using namespace std;

#define mMul(a,b,c)( c = a^b )

int main()
{
   int a, b, c;
   uint8_t chk;
   cin >> hex >> a;
   cin >> hex >> b;

   chk = mMul(a, b, c);

   cin.get();
   cin.get();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Round brackets and bit of changes will do the job here.

Comment: This program produces no output. What is `chk`?

Comment: Check the value of `c`.

Comment: `chk` was just to check the output. But real output is in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Macro is a not a function, but instead its a substitution.  From your code the 'cout' (standard output stream) will expect an object for the output stream. But the macro

```
#define mMul(a,b)   \
  {                   \
    uint8_t prod = 0x00;\
    prod = a^b;         \
 }
```

will not return anything for the cout. Also the '{' will obstruct the flow the 'cout' overloading and the result is the compilation error.

The best approach is using inline function as suggested by Matt McNabb, which is more intelligent and you will get the same result just as macro function.

Another way is modify the macro like this.

```
#define mMul(a,b)  ( { uint8_t prod = 0x00; prod = a^b;  prod;} )
```

and try with GCC compiler.

Answer (score -1):

```
   #include <iostream> // for cin and cout
    #include <stdint.h> // to define uint8_t
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    #define mMul(a,b) (a^b)

    int main()
    {
        uint8_t a, b;

        cin >> hex >> a;
        cin >> hex >> b;


        cout<<setiosflags(ios::uppercase) <<"0x"<<hex<< mMul(a, b);

        cin.get();
        cin.get();  
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the explaination